# WPF Update DataGrid/ListBox GroupItem Text

Tags: datagrid, listbox, binding, grouping

I have a DataGrid/ListBox grouped by ListCollectionView. I have set a control template for GroupItem too. Everything works great.

I show sum of a column in the GroupItem using a converter class i wrote. The problem is that when i edit a cell value, the GroupItem text is not updated.

I appreciate your helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Does your data object implement INotifyPropertyChanged so that the UI is notified properly when the underlying data is changed?

Comment: Yes, i have INotifyPropertyChanged interface implemented and the property handles it.